# Linking SDL2 libraries with CMake

Tags: cmake, sdl-2, mingw-w64

I am trying to get a simple SDL app running using CLion IDE (mingw-w64, CMake).

In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27408853/cmake-failing-to-statically-link-sdl2) it says to link the following libraries in order to get SDL2 working with mingw.

```
-lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -lm -ldinput8 -ldxguid -ldxerr8 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinmm -limm32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -lshell32 -lversion -luuid
```

I know what the first 3 are and how to find and link them using CMake. I have no idea how to include the rest of the libraries because I don't know where they are located or how to get access to them.

Also, is there a difference between `libSDL2` and `lSDL2`? SDL provides libs named `libSDL2.a`, but I always see in examples that it is spelled lSDL2.

Why do the [lazyfoo tutorials](http://lazyfoo.net/SDL_tutorials/lesson01/windows/mingw/index.php) say you only need `lmingw32`, `lSDL2main`, and `lSDL2`? It's what I currently am linking in CMake, but I'm getting undefined references to things like

```
SDL_windowskeyboard.c:617: undefined reference to `ImmGetIMEFileNameA'
```

Comment: Oh, wow. I just add them as is. How are these being referenced? Where are they located on Windows?

target_link_libraries(Dark_Knights ${MINGW32_LIBRARY} ${SDL_MAIN_LIBRARY} ${SDL_LIBRARY} -lm -ldinput8 -ldxguid -ldxerr8 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinmm -limm32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -lshell32 -lversion -luuid)

Comment: Did you try to use `find_package(SDL)` for your purposes? Usually, approach with `find_package()` is easier than manually listing libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to just add the libraries as-is. My example would have been:

`target_link_libraries(Dark_Knights ${MINGW32_LIBRARY} ${SDL_MAIN_LIBRARY} ${SDL_LIBRARY} -lm -ldinput8 -ldxguid -ldxerr8 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinmm -limm32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -lshell32 -lversion -luuid)`